# Сериализация даты как timestamp при записи в кафку

Tags: java, json, spring, timestamp, apache-kafka

У меня есть json, и в нем есть поле с датой
`startDt=2023-01-17T08:59:42.522476Z[UTC]`, когда я кладу json в кафку, то данное поле принимает там значение `1673945982.817186000`, нужно чтобы было как в модели (`2023-01-17T08:59:42.522476Z[UTC]`)

Я пробовал несколько вариантов с ObjectMapper

```
            .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .setDateFormat(StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone(true))
```

```
        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
```

А так же через спринг

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

Ничего из этого не помогло, и в кафке время записывается как timestamp, подскажите какие есть еще варианты

Comment: а дата случайно не тип `Instant` имеет?

Comment: @kami нет ```@NotNull
    private ZonedDateTime startDt;```

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать принудительный формат даты, напр. `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` . А точно используется кафкой  ObjectMapper из контекста спринга с указанными настройками?